# Play youtube video from URL in Exoplayer (android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, video, exoplayer

Hello how to play youtube video from URL in Exoplayer? Official code from codelab doesn't work :(

How to do that? I'm trying to get yt API but in this API i can't find the MP4 url or sth

The old solutions from stackoverflow don't work. A lot of that is deptrecated or code has a lot of exceptions

```
private var playWhenReady = true
    private var currentWindow = 0
    private var playbackPosition: Long = 0

    private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? =null
    private lateinit var  playerView:PlayerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        playerView = findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.video_view);

    }
    private fun releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            playWhenReady = player!!.playWhenReady
            playbackPosition = player!!.currentPosition
            currentWindow = player!!.currentWindowIndex
            player!!.release()
            player = null
        }
    }

    private fun initializePlayer() {
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)
        playerView.player = player
        val uri = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_U6hqn4qhns")
        val mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri)
        player!!.playWhenReady = playWhenReady;
        player!!.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
        player!!.prepare(mediaSource!!, false, false);
    }

    private fun buildMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource? {
        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory =
            DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab")
        return ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(uri)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (SDK_INT >= 24) {
            initializePlayer()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        hideSystemUi()
        if (SDK_INT < 24 || player == null) {
            initializePlayer()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private fun hideSystemUi() {
        playerView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
    }
```

Comment: You can try this library to play youtube videos in android: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

Comment: Vansh can i get audio from this video usign this library?